# Filter disorganized timestamps from a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I would like to know how can I transform the following date_and_time format to epoch.

```
start_date = '2018-01-15 09:00:01
end_date = '2018-01-20 10:30:00'
```

I have the following json file where I would like to filter the data by date_and_time and order by timestamp since the data is disorganized:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":[
        {

            "record_id":258585618,
            "timestamp":"2018-01-18 22:34:34",
            "bytes":29466,

        }
        ,
        {
            "record_id":258585604,
            "timestamp":"2018-01-16 22:33:14",
            "bytes":37892,
        }
        ,
        {
            "record_id":258589578,
            "timestamp":"2018-01-22 22:37:42",
            "bytes":36396,
        }
        ,
        {
            "record_id":258583947,
            "timestamp":"2018-01-15 10:45:50",
            "bytes":36396,
        }
        ,
        {
            "record_id":258589540,
            "timestamp":"2018-01-22 09:15:39",
            "bytes":36396,
        }
    ]
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, I've been reading a lot and I have my exercise half way through.

Answer (score 0):

Use module `datetime`:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-15 09:00:01','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
d.timestamp()
#1516024801.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do.

> Note: I have assumed that the datetime we have are in UTC

```
import datetime as dt

date_string = "2018-01-15 09:00:01"
new_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
epoch_str = (new_date - dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
```

output:

`1516006801.0`